# Do you need to mask a number before retrieving the value stored at a certain byte?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I want to know if one needs to mask a number before retrieving the value stored at a certain byte when doing bit shifting.

Take, for example, this code:

```
short b1 = 1;
short b2 = 2;
short b0 = (short)((b1 << 8) | b2);         //store two values in one variable

Console.WriteLine(b0);                      //b1 and b2 combined
Console.WriteLine((b0 & (255 << 8)) >> 8);  //gets the value of b1
```

As far as I am concerned, doing a right shift drops all bits that are less than the number of bits you've shifted. Therefore, right shifting `b0` by 8 bits will drop the 8 bits of `b2`, leaving just `b1`.

```
Console.WriteLine(b0 >> 8);  //this also gets b1!!
```

I want to find out, is there any need to mask `b0` with `255 << 8` before shifting to get the value of `b1`?

**NB:**
The only need I can think of for masking before retrieving a value is if there is something else stored at a higher byte, such as trying to get back the value of `b2`, in which this code would be used:

```
Console.WriteLine(b0 & 255);  //gets the value of b2
```

Comment: This would be very obvious if you would make `b1` and `b2` `byte`s, and `b0` a `ushort`.  Right shifting `ushort` does not propagate the sign bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to find out, is there any need to mask b0 with 255 << 8 before shifting to get the value of b1?

No, there's no need. So the compiler will omit the masking. Some people think it makes the code easier to understand or protects them against some imagined failure scenario. It's completely harmless.